# Grunt default task only runs first task in the list

Tags: gruntjs

I'm just getting started with grunt and just trying to get a few basic tasks working. 
Here's my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    compass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          config: 'config.rb',
          watch: true
        }
      }
    },
    livecopy: {
      your_target: {
        options: {
          source: "C:/Websites/xxx/styles/screen.css",
          target: "W:/Websites/xxx/styles/screen.css"
        },
      },
    },
    watch: {
      assets: {
        files: ['**//*.css', '**/*.js'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
      },
    },

  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-livecopy');
  grunt.task.registerTask('default', ['compass','livecopy','watch']);
};
```

I can run each of these tasks individually without any issues. When I run the grunt default task, only the first task in the default task list runs. It doesn't matter which order they are in, only the first one runs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run Compass with the watch option it runs `compass watch` which is a blocking task. From the [grunt-contrib-compass docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass):

> watch
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Runs compass watch instead of compass compile. This will use Compass'
>   native watch command to listen for changes to Sass files and recompile
>   your CSS on changes. While much faster than running compass compile
>   each time you want to compile your Sass, Compass becomes a blocking
>   task. This means that if you would like to use it in conjunction with
>   another blocking task, such as watch, you will need to use it in
>   conjunction with a paralleling task such as grunt-concurrent.